# Plotting Options in R: Setting Axis Limits

Tags: r, data-visualization

I am plotting a density estimate for misclassification rate of some classifier using the standard `plot` and `lines` functions. Even though I've set `xlim=c(0.32,0.38)` and `ylim=c(0,100)` within the `plot` command, the x-limits and the y-limits are a bit wider than I'd like. How can I get the bottom left of the plot to have coordinates (0.32,0) and the top right of the plot to have coordinates (0.38, 100)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To strictly enforce the axis limits, include this in your plot call: `xaxs="i", yaxs="i"`.

Check `?par` for lots of other plotting options.

Also, I find this page really helpful for base graphics customization: http://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/RGraphics/chapter3.html